# How to get Time to interact to a webpage via App Insights

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

I am using App Insights from Azure to get the analytic data for a website. 
From the browserTimings and Pageviews settings I am able to get the Load time and receiveDuration.

My website has certain ajax requests loading in (async=true) manner. Due to which in chrome network capture, I am able to see **Finish:2.15 Sec , DOMContentLoaded :1.05 s, Load: 1.57 s**.

Problem statement is How to get the actual time (which attribute) by which the html (DOM) is ready for a user for interaction in App Insights analytics report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is Client Processing Time. You can understand better from this pic.

[image: Clear Explanation]

MS disclaimer:

> The time is measured from when the browser sends the initial HTTP request until all synchronous load events have been processed, including layout and running scripts. It doesn't include asynchronous tasks such as loading web parts from AJAX calls.

For more details: [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#explore-browserclient-side-data)